# Pycharm 2018.3.7 сломан?

Tags: pycharm, pygame, python-3.7

я делаю игру на pygame и использую pycharm 2018.3.7 (так как у меня 32-bit система), когда исполняю код у меня выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py", line 33, in <module>
    from _pydev_bundle.pydev_console_utils import BaseInterpreterInterface
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from _pydevd_bundle import pydevd_thrift
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pydev_console.protocol import DebugValue, GetArrayResponse, ArrayData, ArrayHeaders, ColHeader, RowHeader, \
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\pydev\pydev_console\protocol.py", line 6, in <module>
    _console_thrift = _shaded_thriftpy.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "console.thrift"),
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\__init__.py", line 29, in load
    thrift = parse(path, module_name, include_dirs=include_dirs,
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 502, in parse
    parser.parse(data)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_ply\yacc.py", line 331, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input, lexer, debug, tracking, tokenfunc)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_ply\yacc.py", line 1106, in parseopt_notrack
    p.callable(pslice)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 212, in p_struct
    val = _fill_in_struct(p[1], p[3])
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\parser\parser.py", line 765, in _fill_in_struct
    gen_init(cls, thrift_spec, default_spec)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 103, in gen_init
    cls.__init__ = init_func_generator(default_spec)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.7\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\_compat.py", line 102, in init_func_generator
    new_code = types.CodeType(len(varnames),
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

если что вот код:

```py
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 360
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 60

# colors (R, G, B)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# the window
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()  # the sound
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen.fill(BLACK)

# Game cycle
running = True
while running:
    # controlling fps
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # processing (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check if close
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False    
    # update
    
    # visualisation
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: За что голос против?

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас соблюдаются [ограничения на версию Python для этой версии PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2018.3/install-and-set-up-pycharm.html#300ebdec)?

Comment: да, там написано что максимальная версия это python 3.7